# How does one get string conversion in sympy to behave as pretty print?

Tags: python, sympy

I wanted to be able to get the `str` conversion function in python to act as the pretty print function in sympy (or print as if `init_printing()` was called with any argument(s)). Right now if one calls such a function it only changes the `print` function that prints to the screen. How do I get `str` to behave as `pprint` or other options? In short it would be awesome to be able to get/intercept the output of print somehow in a string and a variable in python itself.

For example I want to be able to do:

```
from sympy import *
x,y=symbols('x y')
x_eq_y = Eq(x,2*y)
x_eq_y_str = str(x_eq_y) # holds 'Eq(x,2*y)' but I want it to hold 'x = 2y' or a latex formula etc
```

is it possible to do that?

Comment: Are you willing to build a class the inherits from `Eq`?

Comment: @StephenRauch sure! Im open for any suggestion. Though, I had in mind to not obsess only about the particular example I gave above. Just in general what the nice print functions to, and get their strings not only print to the screen.

Answer (score 4):

`str` is just one of [printing functions](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/printing.html#printing-functions) available in SymPy. If you want to use another one, use it:

```
x_eq_y_str = latex(x_eq_y)  # get  'x = 2 y' 
x_eq_y_str = pprint(x_eq_y)  # get  x = 2⋅y 
x_eq_y_str = pprint(x_eq_y,  use_unicode=False)  # get  x = 2*y
```

Edit:

Using sympy 1.4 the pprint function does not return the string. This should work instead:

```py
    x_eq_y_str = pretty(x_eq_y)  # get  x = 2⋅y 
    x_eq_y_str = pretty(x_eq_y,  use_unicode=False)  # get  x = 2*y
```