# How can I suppress latex output when using sympy/other, taking derivatives etc in Jupyter

Tags: python, latex, jupyter, sympy

I am using sympy/derivative stuff in jupyter.

So I define a function as follow:

```
def func_one(x,y):
    return  x**2 + 2*y**2
```

Then, with sympy I define some symbols, store my function in a variable 'f', then take its first derivative in a variable 'fprime'.

```
x = sympy.Symbol('x')
y = sympy.Symbol('y')
f = func_one(x,y)
fprime = f.diff(x)
fprime
```

However when I run 'fprime', I get this latex output below, which I cannot use again, is there a way to suppress this latex output?

2

I.e., I want to get:

```
2x
```

Cheers all!

Comment: You aren't saying why you cannot use this output again? You certainly can use `fprime` again in other calculations.  Change you last line to `print(fprime)` , see [here](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/printing.html#str) that is cited by questions similar to yours, or in other cells use`str(fprime)` or `repr(fprime)` as all those give you the `2*x` equivalent. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43420508/8508004) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59401738/8508004) for questions similar to yours.

Comment: And if you don't want the asterisk to show up in your downstream stuff you can always remove it with `str(fprime).replace('*','')`. And you can generalize that to other cases.

Comment: Well, @Wayne, you sir a gent. 
That has worked treat